# Pie Chart Issues With Booleans

Tags: pandas

I have a weird pie chart that isn't coming across right. The column that I'm typing in is a boolean with only true and false values and I'm just looking to make it so it returns two values.

Thank you!

[image: Pie chart]

---

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: Please, add a minimal code to reproduce your issue

Comment: Please include your code as properly formatted text so that people trying to help you don't have to type all of your code out by hand. Likewise, please provide a sample of your `Apple` DataFrame so we can try to reproduce your issue, as @MaxPierini has already indicated

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't post any minimal data sample to reproduce your issue, let's take a look at some fictiv data and maybe you'll get some ideas from that. doing pie charts on booleans can be done this way. Let's assume your data looks like this:

```
var1  Verified
0      A     True
1      A     True
2      A     True
3      A     True
4      A     True
5      A   False 
6      A   False 
7      A   False 
8      A   False 
9      A   False 
10     A   False 
11     B     True
12     B     True
13     B     True
14     B     True
15     B     True
16     B   False 
17     B   False 
18     B     True
19     B     True
20     B     True
21     B     True
22     B     True
23     B   False 
24     B   False 
25     B     True
26     B     True
27     B     True
28     C     True
29     C     True
30     C   False 
31     C   False 
32     C     True
33     C     True
34     C     True
35     C     True
36     C     True
37     C   False 
38     C   False 
39     C     True
40     C     True
41     C     True
42     C     True
43     C     True
44     C   False 
45     C   False 
46     C     True
47     C     True
48     C     True
49     C     True
50     C     True
51     C   False 
52     C   False 
53     C     True
```

You can then do the following:

```
ef labelling(val):
    return f'{val / 100 * len(df):.0f}\n{val:.0f}%'

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(10, 5))

df.groupby('var1').size().plot(kind='pie', autopct=labelling, textprops={'fontsize': 20},colors=['red', 'green','blue'], ax=ax1)

ax1.set_ylabel('Per var1', size=22)

plt.show()
```

which gives you
[image]